# Drop down list in php only working as a default checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to convert my search page from using a checkbox styled method to being able to use a drop down box to select each separate title header as a potential search option. However when converting this the title drop down box still acts as its old checkbox style, being that it only shows the data that is stored within the title name no matter which title is selected.

PHP Section:

```
mysql_select_db($dbDatabase) or trigger_error("Failed to connect to database {$dbDatabase}. Error: " . mysql_error());

// Set up our error check and result check array
$error = array();
$results = array();

// First check if a form was submitted. 
// Since this is a search we will use $_GET
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
$searchTerms = trim($_GET['search']);
$searchTerms = strip_tags($searchTerms); // remove any html/javascript.

if (strlen($searchTerms) < 3) {
  $error[] = "Search terms must be longer than 3 characters.";
}else {
  $searchTermDB = mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerms); // prevent sql injection.
}

// If there are no errors, lets get the search going.
if (count($error) < 1) {
  $searchSQL = "SELECT sid, sbody, stitle, sdescription FROM simple_search WHERE ";

  // grab the search types.
  $types = array();
  $types[] = isset($_GET['body'])?"`sbody` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['title'])?"`stitle` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['desc'])?"`sdescription` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';

  $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); // removes any item that was empty (not checked)

  if (count($types) < 1) 
     $types[] = "`sbody` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; // use the body as a default search if none are checked

      $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'OR';
  $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . " ORDER BY `stitle`"; // order by title.

  $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");


  if (mysql_num_rows($searchResult) < 1) {
     $error[] = "The search term provided {$searchTerms} yielded no results.";
  }else {
     $results = array(); // the result array
     $i = 1;
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) {
        $results[] = "{$i}: {$row['stitle']}<br />{$row['sdescription']}<br />{$row['sbody']}<br /><br />";
        $i++;
     }
  }
}
}

function removeEmpty($var) {
return (!empty($var));
```

HTML Section:

```
<body>
  <?php echo (count($error) > 0)?"The following had errors:<br /><span id=\"error\">" . implode("<br />", $error) . "</span><br /><br />":""; ?>
  <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="searchForm">
     Search For: <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo isset($searchTerms)?htmlspecialchars($searchTerms):''; ?>" /><br />
     Search In:<br />
     Body: <input type="checkbox" name="body" value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['body'])?"checked":''; ?> /> | 
     Title: <form action="form_action.asp">
     <select name="title">
     <option value="Test Simple Search 1">Test Simple Search</option>
     <option value="Searching Made Easy 101">Search Made Easy</option>
     <option value="Gateway to Information">Gateway to Information</option>
     <option value="The Gaming World as we Know it">Gaming World</option>
     <option value="Hundreds of Ants Attacking">Ants Attacking</option>
     <?php echo isset($_GET['title'])?"checked":''; ?> </select> | 
     Description: <input type="checkbox" name="desc" value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['desc'])?"checked":''; ?> /><br />
             Match All Selected Fields? <input type="checkbox" name="matchall" value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['matchall'])?"checked":''; ?><br /><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search!" />
  </form>
  <?php echo (count($results) > 0)?"Your search term: {$searchTerms} returned:<br /><br />" . implode("", $results):""; ?>
```

The option values that are used are the name as the titles stored within stitle within the mysql database. Have I simply implemented them wrong or is my php used after title completely incorrect?

Any advice on what I can do or any code snippets from yourselves would be very appreciated.

Comment: This line seems weird `<?php echo isset($_GET['title'])?"checked":''; ?>`, what's it meant to do?

Comment: Checkboxes allow you to select multiple values from a range, a select lets you select just one, I don't see how their behaviours compare.

Comment: You haven't closed this tag: `<input type="checkbox" name="matchall"..`

Comment: @woodscreative: Of course you can select multiple options, that’s what the [`multiple` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-multiple) on the `select` element is intended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I get your issue.

First if you want to select more than one item in a dropdown, then you need to add the `multiple` attribute to the `select` tag like this `<select name="title" multiple>`
Now when the user holds the CTRL key down and clicks entries, each clicked entry gets selected.

Secondly the data identifying the selected items will now be returned as an array in `$_GET['title']` so if the first 2 options are selected the `$_GET['title']` array would look something like this :-

```
0 - "Test Simple Search 1"
1 - "Searching Made Easy 101"
```

Now in order to re-select the items that were selected by the user when they submitted the form you have to set the `selected="selected"` attribute on each of the `<option>` tags that equate to the selected rows of the dropdown so they look selected when the user sees the form again.

```
<?php
    function was_i_selected($selected_options, $value) {
        if ( in_array($value, $selected_options, true) ) {
           return 'selected="selected"';
        } else {
           return NULL;
        }
    }
?>

 <select name="title" multiple>
 <option <?php echo was_i_selected($_GET['title'], 'Test Simple Search 1');?> value="Test Simple Search 1">Test Simple Search</option>

 <option <?php echo was_i_selected($_GET['title'], 'Searching Made Easy 101');?> value="Searching Made Easy 101">Search Made Easy</option>

 <option <?php echo was_i_selected($_GET['title'], 'Gateway to Information');?> value="Gateway to Information">Gateway to Information</option>

 <option <?php echo was_i_selected($_GET['title'], 'The Gaming World as we Know it');?> value="The Gaming World as we Know it">Gaming World</option>

 <option <?php echo was_i_selected($_GET['title'], 'Hundreds of Ants Attacking');?> value="Hundreds of Ants Attacking">Ants Attacking</option>

</select>
```

Now that look very clumsy and we have not checked that $_GET['title'] actually exists, so I would probably do it like this :-

```
<?php
    $options = array(
             'Test Simple Search 1' => 'Test Simple Search',
             'Searching Made Easy 101' => 'Search Made Easy',
             'The Gaming World as we Know it' => 'Gaming World',
             'Hundreds of Ants Attacking' => 'Ants Attacking'
            );

<select name="title" multiple>
<?php
    foreach ( $options as $val => $label ) {
        if ( ! empty($_GET['title'] ) {
            $sel = in_array($val, $_GET['title'], true) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            echo '<option ' . $sel . ' value="' . $val . '">' . $label . '</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="' . $val . '">' . $label . '</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```